# Google Cloud SQL shutting down intermittently

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have observed multiple times the google cloud sql getting down and coming back after some time.

Please find attached the screen shot below of the No. of read write operations from which I am identifying this issue.  (Unable to attach image as it is asking 10 reputations, I don't know where to get it from, I can email if required)

My typical write operations would be between 12 to 15 writes per second.  I have marked in two instances where the db was down (zero write operations) and the system coming back after 30 mins or so.

This has happened twice today morning (IST) between
1:05 to 1:30 and 3:50 to 4:20 (IST)

Last week too I have noticed this issue where the MYSQL was down for some time.

Any specific reason why this is happening?

If MYSQL was down, why did the  Google Cloud SQL failover did not take over?

Thanks,
Narayana Swamy![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue for about a year. Last week I think I found a fix!

In your console click the project, on the left side click **Storage** > **CloudSQL** then click on your database name. You will see an '*Edit*' button on top. Click that and scroll down to **Activation Policy**, change it to **Always On** and then click **save**. Your DB should now be good to go!

Best of luck

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply.  I did check this.  The setting is already in "Always On" mode.  Any other thoughts? Inputs?.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @narayan, With my instance I changed my SQL from D0 to D1, and even set it from always on to an as needed basis. I've had it like this for 2 and a half days and have noticed it working as expected. There is a price increase but since the DB will only be up when its accessed it should do the trick. Hope this helps you in some way! I really wish D0 had more power or some hints from Google that its performance will be severely lacking.

Comment: Will it affect my billing after changing it to "Always On"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few common causes that you might cause you to see restarts:

1. If you have set the activation policy to "on demand" the instance will be shut down after being [idle for approximately 15 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sometimes_slow).
2. If you change settings such as tier you [instance may be restarted](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#changetiers).
3. As [mentioned on the Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#maintenancerestart) Google occasionally restarts instances for maintanance. Given you question and comments on user1156994's answer this seems to be the most likely cause.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your inputs... But as informed in the comments to user1156994, the setting setting is already in "Always On" Mode.  We are into Machine to Machine communication and our nodes contact these servers 24/7 every 10/15 seconds.  So, the server should not get into idle mode. I am also looking into the possiblity of Internet outage during that time (here in India)...