# Connection made to Google Cloud SQL drops intermittently

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using a Google Cloud SQL using Java-SQL connector. The issue I am facing is that the connection to database drops unexpectedly. While Googling I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169646/google-cloud-sql-shutting-down-intermittently) and tried the solution suggested in the same question.

> In your console click the project, on the left side click **Storage > CloudSQL** then **click** on your **database name**. You will see an **'Edit'** button on top. Click that and scroll down to **Activation Policy**, change it to **Always On** and then click **save**.

But I'm still facing the same issue. Fortunately I have been keeping the logs on Google App Engine and I have attached the snapshot of the exception that occurred while connecting to database.

[image: Google App Engine Log For Cloud SQL connection drop]

Gist of the code that I've posted below is used to establish connection to the database.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
import static com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty.environment;
import static com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development;
import static com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production;

 Connection con=null;
SystemProperty.Environment.Value env = environment.value();
    if(env == Production)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Production Phase");
        // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
        url = "jdbc:google:mysql://<my-project-id>:<cloud-sql-instance>/<database-name>?user=<user-name>&password=<database-password>&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    }//if
    else if(env == Development)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Development Phase");
        // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<database-name>?user=root";
    }//else if
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Is anyone facing the same problem, Please help.

Comment: How often does this happen? Could you post the actual text of some logs? Does it work to connect via the mysql client, rather than through code?

Comment: (1).It happens frequently
(2). `com.webinterface.ConnectToDB connectDB: Connection not made=com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

This is the exception I've logged
(3).I've installed phpmyadmin on Google App Engine for connecting to the Cloud SQL db. It works fine, problem occurs while making connection through the code.

Comment: This seems like something that should be posted to the [Cloud SQL Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list) along with a link to a github repo which can be used to reproduce the behaviour and a description of what can be done to trigger it to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a temporary fix, used following parameters while making connection to Google Cloud SQL

```
url = "jdbc:google:mysql://my-app:mysql2/project-name?user=root&password=password&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
```

**Reference URL:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html