# "Could not create connection to database server" netbeans google cloud sql error

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, google-app-engine, netbeans

I am trying to create my first API using java httpServlet and netbeans which will be connected to a database on google cloud based its [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/master/examples/compute-engine/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/example/ListTables.java) and [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java). I have not created the database, but I was given the necessary credentials and vars to create the connection. So I have downloaded the project from github, and when I tried to open it from netbeans there was some issues concerning dependencies ... So I resolved them, I replaced the credentials with their values and run the project; Unfortunately an error was thrown: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.` I made some searches but did not get any result... Could it be an error from this code ? an error from database security if it was invisible on cloud? Any help is more than appreciated.

```
public class ListTables {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

    String instanceConnectionName = "<foo:foo:bar>";

    String databaseName = "myDatabaseName ";

    String username = "myUsername ";

    String password = "<myPass>";

    if (instanceConnectionName.equals("<insert_connection_name>")) {
      System.err.println("Please update the sample to specify the instance connection name.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    if (password.equals("<insert_password>")) {
      System.err.println("Please update the sample to specify the mysql password.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String jdbcUrl = String.format(
        "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
            + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
        databaseName,
        instanceConnectionName);
 try{
     Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

    /* try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from wf_accounts;");
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
      }
    }*/


 }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
 }
```

**Update**

Same error was thrown when I did this:

```
String jdbcUrl = String.format( 
   "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&" 
   + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory", 
"", 
"");
```

Any hints?

Comment: Did you tried to shutdown your firewall and tried to connect?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633515/connection-made-to-google-cloud-sql-drops-intermittently) question might help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check whether the mysql server is running on.If you are Windows user you can simply

```
Go to Task Manager
Go to Services
then search for your Mysql server(eg:for my case its MYSQL56)
then you will see under the status column it says its not running
by right clicking and select start
```

If it's already running then you have to do as in  mysql Documentation,

You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property

> autoReconnect=true

to avoid this problem

Comment: where should it be added? in which file? And why you're suggesting to reconnect while the connection is denied from the beginning?

Comment: I have update my answer and try this in your Mysql connection URI 
mysql://db_user:db_user@localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true?useUnicode=yes

Comment: still the same error, Plus I told you that I am trying to call a database created by someone else through google cloud ...

Comment: It's simple just as you add a String just append it like this to the end of Db connection URI "?autoReconnect=true". Hope this works

Comment: Please refer this. I can't point out a direct answer with the information you provided https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151149/discussion-between-rahal-kanishka-and-h-al).